# Add Cancel/Close button to Django admin model editor

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I would like to add a Cancel button to the django default admin model editor to enable going back to previous page in case users decide to cancel editing/creating a model. One Option to do that will be extending the 'admin/submit_line.html' and add a Cancel button to it.
However, the default django 'admin/submit_line.html' template already includes a 'Close' button as shown in the code snippet below.

```html
<div class="submit-row">
  {% block submit-row %}
    {% if show_save %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save' %}" class="default" name="_save">{% endif %}
    ...
    {% if show_save_as_new %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save as new' %}" name="_saveasnew">{% endif %}
    {% if show_save_and_add_another %}
      <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save and add another' %}" name="_addanother">{% endif %}
    ...
    {% if show_close %}<a href="{% url opts|admin_urlname:'changelist' %}" class="closelink">{% trans 'Close' %}</a>
    {% endif %}
  {% endblock %}
</div>
```

If I copied the above template and override the show_close variable to True, the Close button will be shown and closes the form as expected. But Isn't there a way  to configure 'show_close' visibility from the models.py or admin.py classes?

Answer (score 2):

override `submit_line.html` template with following content:

```
{% extends "admin/submit_line.html" %}

{% load i18n admin_urls %}

{% block submit-row %}
  {{ block.super }}
  {% if not show_close and adminform.model_admin.show_close_button %}
    <a href="{% url opts|admin_urlname:'changelist' %}" class="closelink">{% translate 'Close' %}</a>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

and then in your admin class you can set field `show_close_button` (can choose anything you want) to True/False and close button will show/hide.

```py
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    show_close_button = True
    ...
```

using `adminform.model_admin.show_close_button` you will get to that field in template.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a custom [`AdminSite`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#adminsite-objects) and override the method [`each_context`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.each_context) to add `show_close` to all admin forms

```
def each_context(self, request):
    context = super().each_context(request)
    context['show_close'] = True
    return context
```

Or you can override `changeform_view` on your model admins to set `extra_context`. You could have a base class that all the admins where you wanted this functionality inherited from

```
def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
    extra_context = extra_context or {}
    extra_context['show_close'] = True
    return super().change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url=form_url, extra_context=extra_context)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `show_close`, `show_save_as_new` and `show_save_and_add_another` do not work.Maybe due to another condition, they default?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change these variables by overriding the `ModelAdmin.changeform_view` method:

```py
class UserAdmin(ModelAdmin):

  def changeform_view(self, request, object_id=None, form_url='', extra_context=None):
    extra_context = extra_context or {}
    extra_context["show_save"] = False
    extra_context["show_save_and_continue"] = False
    extra_context["show_close"] = True
    return super().changeform_view(
      request,
      object_id=object_id,
      form_url=form_url,
      extra_context=extra_context
    )
```